# Python interpreter does not recognize control keys

Tags: python, bash

Previously I ran python 2.7 on Debian Linux terminal (bash). I conveniently use control-f, control-b to move forward/back word.

But it does not work on updated 3.4 version, which generates unreadable symbol.

Is there a way to configure the control-key recognition?

Comment: It works for me in 3.4 version.

Answer (score 1):

If you compiled Python 3.4 from source, you are probably missing the development libraries for readline. The package is typically called libreadline-dev.